# Download and prepare go package's dependencies to be used on another, isolated machine

Tags: go

I've got two machines: `Alice` and `Bob`. `Alice` is not connected to the network, `Bob` is.

I'd like to build and run a go program on `Alice`, but it requires multiple dependencies. Is there a convenient way to prepare all those dependencies from `Bob` so I just have to copy one directory from `Bob` to `Alice` and run `go build` (on `Alice`)?

Comment: You don't need any dependencies to run a go program. Why not build the program on `Bob`, and deploy the binary to `Alice`?

Comment: @JimB One is under Windows, the other on Linux. Is it doable?

Comment: Since I use go v1.5+, I could cross-compile the program I guess.

Comment: try gox for cross compilation: https://github.com/mitchellh/gox

Comment: downvoters, please explain why and how to improve!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the source for compilation is in `$GOPATH`. Copying that to `Alice` will give you everything you need to rebuild the package. Since your source should be in `$GOPATH` as well, there shouldn't be anything else to copy.

If you're using go1.6+, or go1.5 with `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1`, you can put all the dependencies into a `vendor/` subdirectory of your project, to package them together.

Cross-compilation is also very easy in go (unless you require cgo), by setting the `GOOS` and `GOARCH` environment variables.

Go build reference: https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/

http://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5